# ¿Error al determinar el estado indeterminate a mi checkbox?

Tags: jquery, datatables, checkbox

Tengo una consulta y es la siguiente: Tengo un *datatable* que tiene un *checkbox* que cuando se selecciona desde el `<thead>` se selecciona todos los registros pero cuando se selecciona uno en particular el *checkbox* del `<thead>` se vuelve **indeterminate** pero en ciertos momentos deja de funcionar y no se muestra el estado **indeterminate(-)** y al seleccionar el *checkbox* me muestra el siguiente error:

> ````
> jquery.dataTables.js:8109 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_aData' of undefined
>         at _Api.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.js:8109)
>         at _Api.data (jquery.dataTables.js:7180)
>         at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (MantCostos.js:678)
>         at HTMLTableElement.dispatch (vendor.bundle.base.js:3)
>         at HTMLTableElement.q.handle (vendor.bundle.base.js:3)```
> ````

Para volver hacer que funcione el checkbox es limpiando cache.

Me resalta el siguiente código. No se si es la forma correcta de traer los datos de un datatable con paginación ya que ahi es donde me resalta, y el **indeterminate(-)** deja de mostrarse.

```
var info = table.row($(this).closest('tr')).data();
```

---

Éste es mi código:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function crearTabla(datos) {
    let $dt = $('#tbl-buys');
    let dt = $dt.DataTable({
      data: datos,
      order: false,
      columns: [{
          render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
            // ACA controlamos la propiedad para des/marcar el input
            return "<input type='checkbox'" + (full.checked ? ' checked' : '') + "/>";
          },
          orderable: false
        },
        {
          data: 'Producto',
          orderable: false
        },
        {
          data: 'Cantidad',
          orderable: false
        },
        {
          data: 'Precio',
          orderable: false
        },
      ]
    });
    let $total = $('#total');

    // Cuando hacen click en el checkbox del thead
    $dt.on('change', 'thead input', function(evt) {
      let checked = this.checked;
      let total = 0;
      let data = [];

      dt.data().each(function(info) {
        // ACA cambiamos el valor de la propiedad
        info.checked = checked;
        // ACA accedemos a las propiedades del objeto
        if (info.checked) total += info.Precio;
        data.push(info);
      });

      dt.clear()
        .rows.add(data)
        .draw();
      $total.val(total);
    });

    // Cuando hacen click en los checkbox del tbody
    $dt.on('change', 'tbody input', function() {
      let info = dt.row($(this).closest('tr')).data();
      // ACA accedemos a las propiedades del objeto
      info.checked = this.checked;
      
      /**  NUEVO CÓDIGO */
                /**  Verificar si todos están seleccionados */
                var countSelected = 0
                var countTotal = 0
                dt.data().each(function (info) {
                    countTotal += 1;
                    if (info.checked) {
                        countSelected += 1;
                    }
                });

                /** Actualizamos UI según caso */
                if (countSelected === countTotal) {
                    $('thead input').prop("checked", true);
                    $('thead input').prop("indeterminate", false);
                } else if (countSelected === 0) {
                    $('thead input').prop("checked", false);
                    $('thead input').prop("indeterminate", false);
                } else {
                    $('thead input').prop("checked", false);
                    $('thead input').prop("indeterminate", true);
                }
                /** END NUEVO CÓDIGO */
    });
  }
  
  // ACA suscribimos un listener
  $('#btnObtener').on('click', function() {
    let dt = $('#tbl-buys').DataTable();
    let checkeds = dt.data().toArray().filter((data) => data.checked);
    console.log(checkeds);
  });

  crearTabla([{
      "Producto": "Leche",
      "Cantidad": 50,
      "Precio": 3.20
    },
    {
      "Producto": "Azucar",
      "Cantidad": 40,
      "Precio": 2.20
    },
    {
      "Producto": "Gaseosa",
      "Cantidad": 14,
      "Precio": 6.50
    },
    {
      "Producto": "polos",
      "Cantidad": 2,
      "Precio": 32.90
    },
    {
      "Producto": "platos",
      "Cantidad": 10,
      "Precio": 2.00
    },
    {
      "Producto": "tazas",
      "Cantidad": 6,
      "Precio": 2.50
    },
    {
      "Producto": "mesas",
      "Cantidad": 6,
      "Precio": 150.00
    },
    {
      "Producto": "televisor",
      "Cantidad": 1,
      "Precio": 1200.00
    },
    {
      "Producto": "carne",
      "Cantidad": 33,
      "Precio": 15.50
    },
    {
      "Producto": "Menestras",
      "Cantidad": 54,
      "Precio": 2.30
    },
    {
      "Producto": "Paneton",
      "Cantidad": 5,
      "Precio": 20.50
    },
    {
      "Producto": "Arroz",
      "Cantidad": 32,
      "Precio": 2.50
    },
    {
      "Producto": "Huevos",
      "Cantidad": 10,
      "Precio": 3.50
    }
    
    
  ]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" data-page-length="2" id="tbl-buys">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </th>
      <th>Producto</th>
      <th>Cantidad</th>
      <th>Precio</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
<!--<label>Total</label>
<input type="text" id="total" class="form-control" readonly value="0.0" />-->
<br>
<button id="btnObtener">Obtener</button>
```

Comment: Échale un vistazo a esto https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/checkbox.html

Comment: Si pero no me es de mucha ayuda

Comment: Te dejo esta otra referencia https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/

Comment: Estimado esta muy buena esa información pero como haría para traer toda la fila y no solamente el rowId de este ejemplo gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes

Comment: no entiendo tu pregunta, compañero, ¿a qué te refieres con "traer toda la fila" si ya de por sí la librería te da un evento para cuando seleccionas todo el row?

Comment: Estimado me refiero a traer el valor de los campos de acuerdo al checkbox seleccionado por ejemplo el nombre, la posición no tengo muchos conocimientos en usar datatable.

Comment: ok, te escribo un ejemplo de acuerdo a lo que me mencionas, va? qué te interesa saber? los valores que tienen las columnas de esa fila o te interesa saber más allá de eso?

Comment: Me interesa obtener los valores de los campos seleccionados por el checkbox ya que ello lo almacenare en una lista para enviarlo a mi controlador en .net para hacer una actualización en mi base de datos.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102852/discussion-between-fernando-urban-and-dum).